# Linking application windows form using C#.Net to barcode printer Zebra TLP2844

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-4.0, zebra-printers, barcode-printing

Anyone could helps or give solutions what's best to do in linking windows form application using C#.Net to barcode printer machine Zebra TLP2844 ?
Some says had to use ZPL language to barcode machine, some says used sending raw data to the machine. 
When I've investigate using ZebraDesigner Pro as barcode printer designer application, it can be linked to database with field selection on specified database. The database can be recognized such dBase, Access and Excel file. Since our application used SQLServer2008R2, it must be converted to Excel file. But that software designer can only be used for 30days trial.

Now I'm bit confused How the application can generate barcode ID from win form ? Any helps, solutions or do I have to create other class functions in linking win form application to Zebra barcode printer type TLP2844?

Thanks in advance.

regards,
ikadewi

Comment: Did it not come along with a documentrf API or anything alike...?

Answer (score 1):

I have always just sent Raw data to the zebra printers using a filecopy "C:\printebuffer.txt" \uncprinterpath type command to just push the raw data to the port.

Here's a link to the zebra page where you can get manuals.
http://www.zebra.com/us/en/support-downloads.html
There are some sample label buffers there. Usually you can create a 'template' for your main label and just change the data that you need to change on the fly. Hope this helps.

Comment: solved using RawPrinterHelper class on C# with EPL in Stringbuilder ; UpcLabel label = new UpcLabel("603679025109");
label.Print("Zebra  LP2844"); it specified with 12 digits for the label

Comment: Clear solutions from this link : http://nicholas.piasecki.name/blog/2009/03/sending-raw-epl2-directly-to-a-zebra-lp2844-via-c/